# Function in php or javascript - number between -200 and 200 but not zero

Tags: javascript, php

I'm looking for solution in php or javascript to check that given variable is a number between -200 and 200, and not zero.

This is the code I have so far

```
if ($myValue >= -200 && $myValue <= 200) {
    print($myValue);
}
```

Comment: `if(($myValue >= -200 && $myValue <= 200) && $myValue !== 0`)?...

Comment: How about `if ($myValue >= -200 && $myValue <= 200 && $myValue != 0)` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($value != 0 && abs($value) <= 200) {
   echo $value;
}
```

you can use `abs` to shortend condition
http://php.net/manual/pl/function.abs.php

Comment: It may be shorter but comparing both is a little clearer. +1 though.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I totally agree with you :) but I showed possibility only

Answer (score 1):

Just add `&& $myValue != 0` to your `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !empty($myValue) && $myValue >= -200 && $myValue <= 200) {
```

empty will also give you the added benefit of checking if the variable is set. Then it will check it is not 'falsy'. e.g. false, zero, empty array, etc.